# PHP Printing JSON Array Shows the Word "Array" At Top Of Values

Tags: php, arrays, json

Have the following Array that functions perfectly on the site, but before the first output  the word "Array" is printed.

I figure it has to be in the $json_object or $fbdata query but cannot isolate or eliminate it from showing.

```
<?php

$page_id = '{page_id_here}';
$access_token = '{access_token_here}';
//Get the JSON
$json_object = @file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $page_id . 
'/posts?fields=full_picture,link,message&limit=3&access_token=' . 
$access_token);
//Interpret data
$fbdata = json_decode($json_object);

foreach ($fbdata->data as $post )
{
    $posts .= '<div class="col-sm-4">';
        $posts .= '<div class="stay-connected-inner">';
            $posts .= '<div class="stay-connected-info">';
                $posts .= '<div class="stay-connected-left"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></div>';
                $posts .= '<div class="stay-connected-right">';
                    $posts .= '<h5>Title</h5>';
                    $posts .= '<p><a href="' . $post->link . '" target="_blank">' . $post->message . '</a></p>';
                $posts .= '</div>';
            $posts .= '</div>';
            $posts .= '<div class="stay-connected-fig">';
                $posts .= '<p><a href="' . $post->link . '" target="_blank"><img src="' . $post->full_picture . '"></a></p>';
            $posts .= '</div>';
        $posts .= '</div>';
    $posts .= '</div>';
}
//Display the posts
print_r ($posts)

?>
```

Comment: Try using `var_dump($posts);`, also you're missing a semi colon at the end of your `print_r ($posts)`

Comment: var_dump($posts); returned this in text on the site: string(3395) "Array"

Comment: Use `echo $posts;` or if you like `print $posts;`

Comment: @RiggsFolly both of those commands still returned the word "Array" in the same spot

Comment: Where are you even declaring `$posts`?

Comment: @Jon you can append to a variable without declaring it. You'll just get a notice the first time.

Comment: It seems like you declared `$posts` as an earlier, then added a bunch of HTML to it, so when you print out `$posts` it is printing out its 'type' which is `Array` and then printing out all the HTML which is why it says the string is 3395 characters long

Comment: So this is not **ALL the relevant code** we have to assume?

Comment: @RiggsFolly, no he just never declares it so it assumes it to be an array, check out my solution. I tested it on my side and it worked. I thought he must have declared it as an array much earlier before, but he actually just never declares it before the `foreach` loop which is why it is setting it to an array, since he just starts by concatenating it.

Comment: No, if it was just undefined it wouldn't have "Array" at the beginning. That would only result from array to string conversion. If it was undefined it would be created as an empty string before the first append.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. I changed my 'posts' variable to 'postst'. The word 'post' was being used in the URL and that seems to have confused the array in some way.

Updated code:

```
<?php

$page_id = '{page_id_here}';
$access_token = '{access_token_here}';
//Get the JSON
$json_object = @file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $page_id . 
'/posts?fields=full_picture,link,message&limit=3&access_token=' . 
$access_token);
//Interpret data
$fbdata = json_decode($json_object);

foreach ($fbdata->data as $post )
{
$postst .= '<div class="col-sm-4">';
$postst .= '<div class="stay-connected-inner">';
$postst .= '<div class="stay-connected-info">';
$postst .= '<div class="stay-connected-left"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></div>';
$postst .= '<div class="stay-connected-right">';
$postst .= '<h5>Title</h5>';
$postst .= '<p><a href="' . $post->link . '" target="_blank">' . $post->message . '</a></p>';
$postst .= '</div>';
$postst .= '</div>';
$postst .= '<div class="stay-connected-fig">';
$postst .= '<p><a href="' . $post->link . '" target="_blank"><img src="' . $post->full_picture . '"></a></p>';
$postst .= '</div>';
$postst .= '</div>';
$postst .= '</div>';
}
//Display the posts
print_r ($postst);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare `$posts` as a String before your `foreach` loop.

```
<?php

$page_id = '{page_id_here}';
$access_token = '{access_token_here}';
//Get the JSON
$json_object = @file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $page_id . 
'/posts?fields=full_picture,link,message&limit=3&access_token=' . 
$access_token);
//Interpret data
$fbdata = json_decode($json_object);

$posts = ''; // Add this
foreach ($fbdata->data as $post )
{
    $posts .= '<div class="col-sm-4">';
        $posts .= '<div class="stay-connected-inner">';
            $posts .= '<div class="stay-connected-info">';
                $posts .= '<div class="stay-connected-left"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></div>';
                $posts .= '<div class="stay-connected-right">';
                    $posts .= '<h5>Title</h5>';
                    $posts .= '<p><a href="' . $post->link . '" target="_blank">' . $post->message . '</a></p>';
                $posts .= '</div>';
            $posts .= '</div>';
            $posts .= '<div class="stay-connected-fig">';
                $posts .= '<p><a href="' . $post->link . '" target="_blank"><img src="' . $post->full_picture . '"></a></p>';
            $posts .= '</div>';
        $posts .= '</div>';
    $posts .= '</div>';
}
//Display the posts
print_r ($posts)

?>
```

Otherwise it is making `$posts` into an array, so when it is printed, it also prints that it's an array.

Comment: Still dont see where the word `Array` would come from

Comment: @RiggsFolly because he starts by concatenating with `.=` and not having it start with just `$posts='<div class="col-sm-4">';`